# websocket-rails, websocket handshake error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, websocket, ruby-on-rails-4

I followed the docs on the websocket-rails github wiki page, but couldn't overcome this difficulty, I get this error with chrome:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://0.0.0.0:3000/websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 301
```

I installed the `websocket-rails` gem, generated the install, I set successfully `config.middleware.delete Rack::Lock` in `development.rb`; I'm using Rails 4.

I got in the view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var dispatcher = new WebSocketRails('0.0.0.0:3000/websocket');
</script>
```

I got in my `chat_controller.rb`:

```
class ChatController < WebsocketRails::BaseController
   def initialize_session
      puts "Session Initialized"
   end

   def user_connected
     puts 'user connected'
   end
end
```

in my `events.rb`:

```
WebsocketRails::EventMap.describe do
  subscribe :client_connected, :to => ChatController, :with_method => :user_connected
end
```

As you can see, my goal is to display "Session Initialized", and "user connected", in my thin server console each time that someone goes on a page. Between, I run the server with `bundle exec thin start`, but I got a javascript error instead (websocket connection failed error 301).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the members of the Websocket Rails IRC, I found out that in my route, I was appending the locale before every path, so it coudln't find it.

Check your `routes.rb` if someone hit that issue too !

Comment: will routes.rb route for `ws` protocol?