# Can not connect web socket with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, sockets, amazon-web-services, websocket

I want to connect to my web socket that put on amazone instance with some ip. I can connect my web socket with some ip and port with google rest client app and its working very well.
Screen Shot :
[image]

But if i want to connect this with java script it can not connect. This is working fine before 2-3 month. i have not change and thing but its not working now.
If i want to connect with firefox it produce an error.
Here is my code :-

```
function init() {
           var host = "ws://XX.XX.XXX.XXX:XXXX"; // SET THIS TO YOUR SERVER


                try {
                  var socket = new WebSocket(host);
                   // alert('WebSocket - status ' + socket.readyState);
                    log('WebSocket - status ' + socket.readyState);

                    socket.onopen = function (msg) {
                        alert('open');
                        alert("Welcome - status " + this.readyState);
                        log("Welcome - status " + this.readyState);

                        if (this.readyState != 1)
                        {
                            reconnect();
                        }
                    };
                    socket.onmessage = function (msg) {
                      //  alert("Received: " + msg.data);
                        log("Received: " + msg.data);

                    };
                    socket.onclose = function (msg) {
                     //   alert("Disconnected - status " + this.readyState);
                        log("Disconnected - status " + this.readyState);
                    };
                } catch (ex) {
                    alert(ex);
                    log(ex);
                }
                $("msg").focus();
            }
```

This is alerting status 0 and error show in console :-

```
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://XX.XX.XXX.XXX:XXXX.


var socket = new WebSocket(host);
```

Comment: Could you ping ip from machine you get connection error? Also check websocket server is running

Comment: websocket is running and also get connected with google rest client app, you can see on screen shot it gives error only with webpage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd try your code and for me is working just fine, I'd test it with this webpage: https://www.websocket.org/echo.html , maybe could be helpful for testing purposes. But also i found this question: [websocket-rails, websocket handshake error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20459935/websocket-rails-websocket-handshake-error) , maybe also help.
However i'd just change the host in your code to this:"ws://echo.websocket.org", and everything works without problems.
Hope you find a solution and that this info was of any help. Here's your code that i used for the test:

```
function init() {
var host = "ws://echo.websocket.org"; 
    try {
      var socket = new WebSocket(host);
       alert('WebSocket - status ' + socket.readyState);
        socket.onopen = function (msg) {
            alert('open');
            alert("Welcome - status " + this.readyState);

            if (this.readyState != 1)
            {
                reconnect();
            }
        };
        socket.onmessage = function (msg) {
          alert("Received: " + msg.data);
        };
        socket.onclose = function (msg) {
           alert("Disconnected - status " + this.readyState);
        };
    } catch (ex) {
        alert(ex);

    }
    $("msg").focus();
}
```

*Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I have already tested with this web socket it's work fine but not work with my socket. but it can connect with google rest client socket connection you can see the screenshot. What i am doing wrong.

Comment: This is connected with my socket but automatically disconnected.

Comment: ok, is hard to reproduce the error you get since i don't know  your web socket. Maybe you already try it but i will ask anyway, did you try changing the "ws" to "wss"?... I try your code again with other socket and got the same error like you, then i just change to "wss://x.x.x.x:xxxx" and it worket for me in firefox.

Comment: Also check if you need any authentication from javascript to your socket. I'm running out of ideas, but i found thi page: http://www.developerfusion.com/article/143158/an-introduction-to-websockets/, there you have some code example that might help you.