# Javascript Websocket onopen not being called

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, websocket, client

I'm trying to create a simple server (Python) and client (Javascript) using websocket, but wondering why the onopen in Javascript not being called

Server side (server.py) [credit to](https://towardsdatascience.com/3-lines-of-python-code-to-write-a-web-server-46a109666dbf)

```
import os
from http.server import HTTPServer, CGIHTTPRequestHandler
os.chdir('.')
server_object = HTTPServer(server_address=('', 8080), RequestHandlerClass=CGIHTTPRequestHandler)
server_object.serve_forever()
```

Client side (index.html) [credit to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37423724/5737856)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var host = "ws://SERVER_IP:8080"; 
    try {
      var socket = new WebSocket(host);
       console.log('WebSocket - status ' + socket.readyState);
        socket.onopen = function (msg) {
            console.log("Open - status " + this.readyState);
        };
        socket.onmessage = function (msg) {
            console.log("Received: " + msg.data);
        };
        socket.onclose = function (msg) {
           console.log("Disconnected - status " + this.readyState);
        };
    } catch (ex) {
        console.log(ex);
    }
</script>
```

When I run the code, server will print `CLIENT_IP - - [21/Aug/2021 15:22:18] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -`  and client in Google Chrome in console will print

```
WebSocket - status 0                                      @ index.html:5 - console.log('WebSocket - status ' + socket.readyState);
WebSocket connection to 'ws://SERVER_IP:8080/' failed:    @ index.html:4 - var socket = new WebSocket(host);
Disconnected - status 3                                   @ index.html:13 - console.log("Disconnected - status " + this.readyState);
```

I'm wondering anything I have missed so that the server has response but onopen is not called? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

var socket ...   Is probably local to function init(), so it is lost when you exit the function.

Comment: I have updated the code, but still the same.

Comment: The connection failed, therefore No onopen ().

Comment: The server do receive the connection ```CLIENT_IP - - [21/Aug/2021 15:22:18] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - ```

Comment: The server receives connection however this does mit mean that the handshake ist correct, therefore the client failes

Comment: any suggestion to reverse it?

Answer (score 0):

Finally find a post that can be a big help about [websockets](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html).

First is to install a module of websockets `pip install websockets` for python2 or `pip3 install websockets` for python3

Server

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# WS server that sends messages at random intervals

import asyncio
import datetime
import random
import websockets

async def time(websocket, path):
    while True:
        now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + "Z"
        await websocket.send(now)
        await asyncio.sleep(random.random() * 3)

start_server = websockets.serve(time, "127.0.0.1", 5678)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Client

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>WebSocket demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var ws = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:5678/"),
                messages = document.createElement('ul');
            ws.onmessage = function (event) {
                var messages = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0],
                    message = document.createElement('li'),
                    content = document.createTextNode(event.data);
                message.appendChild(content);
                messages.appendChild(message);
            };
            document.body.appendChild(messages);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If your server is on cloud, use `0.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1` in server code and surely use `SERVER_IP` instead of `127.0.0.1` in client code too